# I Need advice about what docking station should I get for my laptop

Tags: laptop, docking-stations

I have my laptop: idea pad c340-14IWL (Product Number: 81N400AXIV), connected to a monitor HDMI connection, keyboard, mouse USB connected, a speaker connected via headphone jack, and a type c-ethernet adapter for wired internet connection.

This is all very cumbersome to plug and unplug from the laptop. So I want something to help with the clutter and hopefully be able to make the setup work with the plugging of one wire to the laptop if possible. But I have no experience with hardware and am unsure if a docking station will work for me (Or even if A docking station is what I need).

After some reading, I think this might be what I need: [docking option](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09TZJQTWQ). but I am unsure if it will work for my model (at the start) or if perhaps there is a better safer option out there, I want something as minimal and cheap as can be while being reliable.

[image]